# Would delayElement be susceptible to a DoS attack?

Tags: performance, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a service that authenticates a user and I put `delayElement` for `2 seconds` when it is about to return a 401.

When I run through artillery, it seems to start timing out some of the requests and I was wondering what kind of resources are used for `delayElement` as I was sort of hoping it just switches context away from the current request and goes to the next one that needs processing and just alarm itself back later to return the response.

```java
  private Mono<R> addDelaySpecifiedInServiceResponse(AuthServiceResponse<R> serviceResponse) {
    return fromCallable(serviceResponse::getOperationResponse)
        .delayElement(serviceResponse.getDelay(), Schedulers.newParallel("penalty"));
  }
```

I tried different schedulers and seem to get a similar result.

Comment: the fact that you call `newParallel` to provide a `Scheduler` to `delayElement` means that you're creating a pool of threads each time you call the `addDelaySpecifiedInServiceResponse` method. isn't that an issue?

Comment: yup that was the issue.  Though I am not sure if newParallel would be good or would newBoundedElastic would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delayElement` in essence schedules a task on the provided `Scheduler` (or the common parallel scheduler by default), so yes it "alarms itself back later" if I understand your comment correctly.