# Which scheduler should I use for a "penalty box" when I do delayElement in WebFlux?

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am trying to implement a "penalty box" for unsuccessful attempts to use our API when it is dealing with security tokens.  This extends my previous question [Would delayElement be susceptible to a DoS attack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72131993/would-delayelement-be-susceptible-to-a-dos-attack) which is isn't.

Here's my handler at the moment.

```
.onErrorResume(
  SecurityException.class,
  ex -> {
    ServerWebExchangeUtils.setResponseStatus(
      exchange, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    ServerWebExchangeUtils.setAlreadyRouted(exchange);
    securityLog.warn("security error obtaining claims: {}", ex.getMessage());
    return chain
      .filter(exchange)
      .delayElement(
        Duration.ofMillis(authProperties.getPenaltyDelayInMillis()), 
        penaltyScheduler
      )
      .then(
        respondWithUnauthorized(config, exchange, "invalid_token"));
      })
```

I have my scheduler as `Schedulers.newParallel("penalty")` which allows for parallel threading.  But I am not sure if parallel would be the better scheduler or should I just use boundedElastic?

Comment: delayElement uses the common parallel scheduler by default. What is your goal by customizing this?

Answer (score 0):

i see no reason as to why you would use parallel.

A parallel scheduler guarantees that work will be scheduled over several cores. Running things in parallel is only beneficial if you need raw computing power, for instance if you need to do heavy mathematical calculations.

Using a parallel scheduler also has a setup time as we need to send instructions to the other cpus, they need to allocate threads etc.

What you want is to allocate threads that are going to most likely spend 99% of their time waiting, which means there is no reason whatsoever that you need the multiple cpu core guarantee.

`boundedElastic` will create a scheduler with an upper bounded limit which will suffice. `Async` work is more about orchestration, and not raw cpu-power so the framework will handle the threading and optimization for you as efficient as possible.

Thats the reason for using webflux, so we dont need to think about those things.

Comment: I'm not sure suggesting `BoundedElasticScheduler` is a great move here. It will create one thread/`Worker` per use of the `Scheduler` which could amount to even more threads than with `newParallel`...